# Add datelist to Array collections C#

Tags: arrays, linq, foreach

I have 30 string[4] elements which contains user data. I have 30 date generic list collection. How to add each date as 5th element in each one string[] collection?

```
List<string> _datefromexcel = new List<string> ();
foreach(DataColumn c in dtRow.Table.Columns) {
    if (Information.IsDate(c.ColumnName)) {
        _datefromexcel.Add(c.ColumnName);
    }
}

List<string> newlist = lst.GetRange(startrange, count);

int i = 0;
var query = from s in newlist
let num = i++
    group s by num / 4 into g
select g.ToList();
var results = query.ToArray();

foreach(var item in _datefromexcel) {
    results.insert(5, item);
}
```

This is insert all date value after 5th element.

Please advice the best way to insert each date value as 5 element in array collection.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you won't be able to "insert" anything into an array, since it has a static size. You can add things to a list, however, because a list can dynamically resize itself.

```
var results = query.ToList();

foreach (var item in _datefromexcel) {
    results.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

If you need to, you can call ToArray after the foreach loop is finished:

```
return results.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop instead:

```
var results = query.ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
     results[i].Add(_datefromexcel[i]);
```

The LINQ way will be a bit ugly:

```
var results = query.Zip(_datefromexcel, (l, d) => l.Concat(new[] { d }).ToList()).ToArray();
```